# Does not want to be inserted as html in CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

onOk: function() {

```
        var dialog = this;

        var contentFromTextarea = dialog.getValueOf('tab-main','content');
        var rowArray = new Array();
        var cellArray = new Array();

        var row = '';

        rowArray = contentFromTextarea.split(';');

        for (var i = 0; i < rowArray.length-1; i++) 
        { 
            cellArray[i] = rowArray[i].split(':');
            row += '<div>' + '<span>' + cellArray[i][0] + '</span>' + '<span>' + cellArray[i][1] + '</span>' + '</div>'                                    

        }

        row = '<div>' + row + '</div>';
        editor.insertHtml(row);
    }
```

Does not want to be inserted as html in CKeditor. Why?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try displaying "row" just before you run the editor.insertHtml(row);
 command just to make sure you html tags are well formed. why are you adding a div tag inside another div tag?

Comment: What you meen about "displaying row"? How can I do this? Sorry, this is my first work with ckeditor. Earlier it was table tags. I'm trying to make a plugin: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/Insert-information-in-the-table.-My-plugin.#comment-132595